# How to make Rails 3 DELETE resource action accept POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm running into a dilemma here. The Firefox Add-Ons SDK only allows PUT and POST requests via its API. I am using the following route in Rails: "resource :users"

I can easily override the PUT to be:

```
"match 'users/:id' => 'users#update', :via => [:post, :put]
```

However, I can't do this again for DELETE as I also need to :post to the same URL again. Do I need to create a new route all-together and abandon the resourceful way of doing things? Is there a way to have POST behave like a DELETE on the Firefox side instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in the high-level Request api, however you could implement something using the lower level xhr api:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/api-utils/docs/xhr.html

This provides access to Firefox's underlying XmlHttpRequest implementation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I've also figured out that you could fake PUT and DELETE by doing a POST to http://domain.com/url?_method=PUT.